# Pixel Qi screen operation

Tags: display, backlight

I just installed Pixel Qi screen (PQ101WX01) on my Acer Aspire One D270, but I can only control dimming of the screen through OS. 
Dimming doesn't make it more readable in the sunlight, and going to sleep turns the screen completely black.

How do I shut down backlight and switch Pixel Qi screen mode of operation to readable in the sun?

I have access to both Windows 7 and Ubuntu (13 or more newer).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have this(**PQ101WX01**) screen personally ,but as far as I can Suggest is to make it more readable in sunlight you should increase the brightness of the screen and for sure your default OS will have this feature no matter its windows or Linux or any other.Dimming makes it less readable in sunlight because of the high intensity of sun due to which your eye adjusts automatically to the bright light and you cant see the screen and it goes opposite in the dark/dim light when you need to dim your screen brightness .

Comment: Ah, you see, Pixel Qi made a screen with two modes of operation, normal and reflective (similar to e-ink) mode, which can be turned on by switching the backlight on and off. I am searching for this backlight on and off control, out of the mentioned reason.

Comment: Try using the shortcut key fn+f2

Comment: No, fn+f2 doesn't do anything.
Here's the quote from Clover's SunBook having PixelQi display: "In daylight, the backlight can be turned off completely, cutting the power consumption, extending battery life, and reducing eyestrain. Reflective mode provides 1024 x 600 resolution in black & white." This is the feature I am searching for.

Comment: Hey do you have theirhelpline number or consumer support email id? ? just try they will help you far better then what you can get from here.

Comment: One would believe so, but they are not answering emails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is this little pixelqi program seting backlight on or off :

#!/bin/sh -e

# backlight on off

card=`find /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/ -name "brightness" -a -not -path "*video*"`

if [ `cat $card` = "0" ]; then
echo 3500 | sudo tee -a $card;
else
echo 0 | sudo tee -a $card;
fi

exit 0

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers and help. After talking to the Pixel Qi company, it seams like the screen I got was a fake one, so be careful when ordering off ebay.

Comment: Did they say how you would actually do it? It might help someone who actually has this problem, rather than leaving it as "I got a dodgy black market item that dosen't work"

Comment: After a disscussion with the director of Pixel Qi and their technician, and the seller slkbid2769 on ebay: this person is selling fake screens and should be avoided, I still haven't got my money return.